# When do we need pass queryset argument to PrimaryKeyRelatedField in Django REST Framework?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, relationship

I was reading DRF docs and in primaryKeyRelatedField i saw the arguments as

> queryset - The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input. Relationships must either set a queryset explicitly, or set read_only=True.

I understand that PrimarykeyRelatedField is used to serialize relationships using primary keys. However, i am not able to understand why do we need to pass queryset as an argument to PrimaryKeyRelatedField. I coundn't find any examples in docs, i saw some examples online but still not able to figure out. Please help me to understand this with any use case or example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit older question but for some still searching - you can use it in process of deserialization

```
entity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Entity.objects.all())
```

Thanks to this you are able to specify only primary key in create/update request body:

```
{
    "entity": 1
}
```

this will automatically look for the entity, providing 400 response code if not found in given queryset you provided. If it is found, you are provided instance of the Entity in validated_data of used serializer.

```
serializer.validated_data["entity"] # this will return Entity object
```